# how do you unistall a python package/library

Tags: python, linux, uninstallation

I installed `python-memcached`

```
/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/python_memcached-1.54-py2.6.egg
```

Now, I am having some problems with my django webserver, getting server 500 error.

How do I uninstall `python-memcached`?

Comment: What linux are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Suse linux you can use yum:

```
yum remove python-memcache
```

Comment: I'm on suse linux. can I just remove the .egg file?

Comment: You can, but might upset the package manager. How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: python setup.py install