# Uninstalling Python3.5 from Linux RHEL

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, rhel, make-install

I installed Python3.5 in Linux machine using `configure`, `make`, `make install` and made it default over existing Python2.6 . Now I want to uninstall Python 3.5 as it is not supporting `zlib`. How do I uninstall default Python 3.5. Linux is RHEL6.7.

Comment: For the record, some authors put a `make uninstall` option in the makefile. However, the easiest way would probably be just to `rm` the python3.5 binary. Type `which python3.5` (replace `python3.5` with whatever command you actually use to open a Python 3.5 interactive interpreter) to find the location of the binary and then remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you unistall a python package/library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757684/how-do-you-unistall-a-python-package-library)

Answer (score 0):

you probably can remove the directory that contain the new installation. 
but the main thing is to remove it from the $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

To re-add Python 3.x, go here to use a software collection which installs "along side" the original 2.6 - so no collisions/corruption.  http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/get-started-rhel6-python/

This is for 3.4, but you can use these instructions for 3.5 too.

Answer (score 0):

Because python is integral into the RHEL OS, please explain what you mean by:
"and made it default over existing Python2.6 ." Otherwise attempts to "uninstall" your working python install might leave you with a broken RHEL install.